# QGIS Server, Postgres (PostGIS) data, and password less data access with pg_service.file on Windows

Tags: postgresql, qgis-server, iis

We are trying to put set QGIS Server on Windows via IIS. The project on the QGIS Desktop uses `pg_service.conf` file without problem. When the project is moved to the Windows server, we set the `PGSERVICEFILE` variable, it is not loaded.

Does anybody have hint, how to setup IIS server along with `PGSERVICEFILE` configuration option, so it works?

Comment: pg_hba.conf and pg_ident.conf files need some configuration. see https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p2034/postgres-using-integrated-security-on-windows-on-localhost